# Ping Federate: Error while getting Access Token

Tags: pingfederate

I  am trying to retrieve 'Access Token' using  'Authorisation Code'  grant type using Ping Federate.

Ping federate is configured with 
Callback URL,
Auth URL,
Access Token URL,
Client ID and Client Secret
Scope: openid
 
But when i try to request for Access token using Postman 'Get Access Token' feature, i am getting below error.

"The global default access token manager is not available for the selected client and authentication context"

I have configured Access token manager to the client.

Anybody have come across such error and would appreciate if you could help with this.

```
PingFederate Logs:
entityId: devenuat (null)

virtualServerId: null

Binding: oauth:authz

relayState:

params: {code=IVFUPjrUIMYVP8Djti9Bkwz3gLDbygS5_nMAAAAC, state=}

Endpoint: http://ec2-34-255-9-65.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/authentication/login?code=IVFUPjrUIMYVP8Djti9Bkwz3gLDbygS5_nMAAAAC&state= <http://ec2-34-255-9-65.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/authentication/login?code=IVFUPjrUIMYVP8Djti9Bkwz3gLDbygS5_nMAAAAC&state=> 

SignaturePolicy: BINDING_DEFAULT



2019-11-29 11:20:35,305  DEBUG [org.sourceid.servlet.HttpServletRespProxy] adding lazy cookie Cookie{PF=hashedValue:26e1qHIcgNhYfWhMIqK35xMF_mU; path=/; maxAge=-1; domain=null} replacing null

2019-11-29 11:20:35,305 tid:26e1qHIcgNhYfWhMIqK35xMF_mU DEBUG [org.sourceid.websso.servlet.ProtocolControllerServlet] ---REQUEST (POST)/as/token.oauth2 from 92.123.73.225:

---PARAMETERS---

code:

   IVFUPjrUIMYVP8Djti9Bkwz3gLDbygS5_nMAAAAC

grant_type:

   authorization_code

redirect_uri:

   http://ec2-34-255-9-65.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/authentication/login <http://ec2-34-255-9-65.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/authentication/login> 

client_id:

   devenuat
```

Comment: What's the authentication context that you are using? Can you add the DEBUG-level log entries?

Comment: Vinod, can you edit your question and add more of the log (use the `PRE` formatting)? Comments aren't the place to do that. The other thing that you can do is to open a support case with Ping.

Comment: @AndrewK. Oh I am sorry. Now I have added logs from the ping federate server.  The Auth Code is coming as null in my Application, so I could not exchange it for Token.

Comment: @VinodKumarPayakatVenugopal Have you mapped your access token manager to the policy contract in the "Access token mapping" section?